# Remove duplicate values from a list

Tags: python, list

Code first:

```
li = [32,45,23,66,66,89,27]
print li
for k in li:
    if k == 66:
        li.remove(k)
print li
```

Result:

```
> [32, 45, 23, 66, 66, 89, 27] 

> [32, 45, 23, 66, 89, 27]
```

Here is my question: when I remove the first **66**, the second one and the other items will move forward one index, and the next `k` will be **89**. The second **66** is still there. How can I remove it?

Comment: You shouldn't remove items while you iterate through them, it is better to use a list comprehension to make a new list with the correct values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer to [Loop problem while iterating through a list and removing recurring elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131457/loop-problem-while-iterating-through-a-list-and-removing-recurring-elements/7131481#7131481) to understand why you get this problem.

In this case, you can just do:

```
li = [item for item in li if item != 66]
```

to make a new list.

The list comprehension will also be faster if you have to do a lot of `remove`s because each `remove` has to traverse the whole list, while the list comprehension traverses the whole list only once.

Answer (score 3):

The most common way to do this is to iterate over a *copy* of a list, rather than the original list:

```
for k in li[:]:
    #do stuff
```

I prefer to use a list comprehension however:

```
[k for k in li if k != 66]
```

Comment: Your wording is not very clear to me, list comprehension does not mutate the list.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want to do is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python). So in your case:

```
li = [32,45,23,66,66,89,27]
print li
li[:] = [x for x in li if x != 66]
print li
```

of course if you **want**  to do it with a normal for loop you can always iterate `li` reversed:

```
li = [32,45,23,66,66,89,27]
print li
for k in reversed(li):
    if k == 66:
        li.remove(k)
print li
```

But notice, that this is very inefficient. Because `remove` **searches** for the first occurance and removes that. So you effectively iterate the list many times.

Comment: We don't know that he needs to maintain the same actual list object. He probably doesn't.

Comment: There's no reason to mutate the old list. In this case, rebinding name `li` is actually slightly (about 10%) faster. Not to mention it avoids unnecessary code complexity.